# Maximum Intensity for Gaussian Beam

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, laser, geometric-optics

So I wanted to find out the maximum intensity for a Gaussian beam for a given aperture $D$ which is valid for near and far field, as a function of distance $z$, wavelength $\lambda$ and initial power $P_0$.

Of course you expect the solution as you take the limit $z=\infty $ to become:
$$
w(z) = w_0 \, \sqrt{ 1+ {\left( \frac{z}{z_\mathrm{R}} \right)}^2}=\lim_{z \to +\infty} \frac{w_0z}{z_\mathrm{R}}=\frac{z\lambda}{\pi w_0}
$$
$$
I_{0} = {2P_0 \over \pi w^2(z)}=\lim_{z \to +\infty}{2P_0 \pi w_0^2 \over \lambda^2 z^2} \cong {P_0 \pi D^2 \over 2\lambda^2 z^2}
$$
Where $P_0$ is the beam power and $w_0$ is the initial waist radius of the Gaussian Beam. I used the approximation that aperture $D\cong 2w_0$.

Intuitively you also expect the peak intensity that is achievable for any finite $z$ to be higher than ${2P_0 \pi w_0^2 \over \lambda^2 z^2}$, but finding the exact equation is quite troublesome.

Comment: What is your question? You have not stated a question in your post as far as I can see. You will get the best results on this forum if you state **one** clear question and provide details for potential answerers to understand the context.

Comment: The question is what is the equation that is also valid for near field as well as far field for maximum intensity

Comment: The beam exiting an aperture is not a Gaussian beam. It's intensity pattern will usually be assumed to be the same as the pattern of whatever beam entered the other side of the aperture (or zero, outside the aperture area).

Comment: I second The Photon. You need to use a diffraction integral to know the actual intensity on axis and it will be closer to your initial beam close to your aperture, then you will have fresnel rings with either higher or lower intensity and in the far-field it will be smoother but different from a gaussian with size of your aperture as the source (at aperture), because your source is a truncated gaussian and that is extremely different from a gaussian.